# Loop printing correct answer but adding wrong one to map?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, bufferedreader

[image]

(Right click and open image in new tab to see it bigger)

nothing much to say but the code:

```
System.out.println("map add:" + parts[i].split("=")[0] + "=" + list);
        map2.put(parts[i].split("=")[0], list);
```

prints out the exact same thing as what is added to the map but what is printed and what is on the map are completely different?
why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding the same list at each iteration, and hence the keys are referencing the same list (see figure below).
What you're actually doing is this :

1. You create a list containing the values `[root, like]` and you associate this list with the key `root`
2. In the second iteration, you clear the list and you add `[eat, it]` to this list and associate it with another key `xsubj`.

Since you did'nt create a new object, the keys `root` and `xsubj` point to the same list object and hence each change on the list will be reflected for all the keys that share it.

[image]

So that's why at the end you got this output.

Instead of calling `clear()`, create a new list at each iteration.

```
for(int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++){
  list = new ArrayList<>();
  list.add(...);
  /**
   * The code
  **/
}
```

Comment: Ok that makes sense so clear isn't doing anything and I keep adding more to the list but as it only takes the first and second it repeates the same thing?

Comment: @user2871826 See my edit and tell me if you understand what you were doing.

Comment: Yeah I understand for some reason I assumed clear() would be like deleting everything and have the same affect as creating a new one but obviously I was mistaken.